# Spring Roo project cannot find org.springframework.roo.annotations:jar:1.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, spring, maven, primefaces, spring-roo

I generated a primefaces project via spring-roo. The first thing was to invoke following command without touching generated code:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Maven gave an error indicating that it cannot locate `org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.annotations:jar:1.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`  dependency. The project contains following repositories:

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Is this any other repository where I can find `org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.annotations:jar:1.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`  dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found why above dependency cannot be found. The generated pom.xml does not contain spring-roo snapshot repository. If you add following dependency, the project compiles:

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
```

I also forked spring-roo code, fixed the template and sent the fix to be merged. Following github repository contains the fixed spring-roo version:

https://github.com/hkarakose/spring-roo